# What is the difference in creating uvm_reg_field with or without get_full_name()

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What is the difference between

```
this.ModuleEn=uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("ModuleEn");
```

and

```
this.ModuleEn=uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("ModuleEn",,get_full_name());
```

I don't see difference in simulation results.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd and 3rd arguments to `create()` affect the lookup of factory overrides. If you have no overrides (which is typical for RAL models), these arguments will not make any difference.

The second argument would be used to set the context of the override if you were creating this inside a uvm_component. The third argument is used to set a context via a string path, which in this case is being set by the register's path.